# Meizu MX4 Bootloop

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

i just received my new MX4 today but after the first update it won't boot anymore. It is just stuck in a bootloop forever, no adb or fastboot available. If i reboot it to recovery still no fastboot and adb says the device is offline. Do you have any idea how i can solve the problem and/or reflash a  new version on the phone?

Comment: maybe something here: http://meizufans.eu:4567/forum/topic/871/mx4-almost-bricked-after-4-1-2a-ota-update

Comment: hmm doesn't really help in my case i can only boot to recovery but can't do anything there since adb says the device is offline. I haven't found a way to make fastboot work

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: The recovery from http://people.canonical.com/~alextu/tangxi/recovery/recovery.img 
does work while the one that is included in the RC and stable Version does not work. With power + volume down i managed to get fastboot and flash this recovery then with power + volume up to get to recovery and voila adb was in recovery mode and it was possible to use ubuntu-device flash  (ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/rc/meizu.en)